# ¿Qué debe hacer realmente cada "capa" de mi arquitectura?

Tags: spring-boot, servidor, backend, arquitectura

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Spring (Web, Data JPA y Security) consistente en una API REST que permite hacer ciertas operaciones sencillas sobre una base de datos. Existe un sistema de usuarios, y cada usuario solo tiene acceso a ciertos "recursos" de cada endpoint. Por ejemplo, si fuera de libros (no lo es), cada usuario solo podría acceder a "sus" libros.

Mi aplicación está estructurada bajo el (hasta donde yo sé) habitual patrón controlador-servicio-repositorio; donde el controlador recibe las peticiones web, el servicio gestiona la "lógica de negocio" o casos de uso; y el repositorio es un simple conector a la base de datos (en Spring Data, un `JpaRepository`).

Un caso de uso es que cada usuario pueda acceder a los `Libro` con atributo `owner` que sea el ID del usuario, pero no a los registrados por otros usuarios. ¿Dónde debería gestionar esto? Veo dos posibles formas de hacer esto:

1. Crear una consulta personalizada con JPQL para obtener los libros por ID de dueño, o desde el `Repository` llamar a findAll con ese filtro.

```java
public interface LibroRepository extends JpaRepository {
    @Query("SELECT l FROM Libro b WHERE l.owner = :owner")
    public Libro findByOwner(int owner);
}
```

2. Uso el método `findAll` y en el service hago un `filter` sobre los resultados.

```java
public class LibroService {
    @Autowired
    LibroRepository libroRepository; // Esto iría inyectado por constructor

    public List<Libro> getLibrosByOwner(int ownerId) {
        return libroRepository.findAll()
            .stream()
            .filter(b -> b.owner.id == ownerId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

En el primer caso, creo que no es lo más adecuado porque buscar por owner es parte de la lógica de negocio (owner no es la clave primaria, y a la capa de datos no le debería importar la lógica de negocio). Pero en el segundo, estás obteniendo todo el rato todos los datos de la BBDD, y luego filtrándolos, lo que seguramente sea más lento de hacer en Java que directamente por el SGBD cuando lanzas la consulta (caso 1).

¿Qué es lo más recomendable en este caso? ¿Estoy equivocado en alguna parte de mi planteamiento?

Comment: Tu desacoplas el diseño  en controladores, servicios y repositorios, pero entre ellos debe existe un flujo, existen interrelaciones, procesos, validaciones y un largo etc. La mejor solución no pasará nunca por un caso acotado y simplificado como lo has presentado, porque si el problema fuera solo lo expuesto la respuesta es la (1) y punto. Y es que no hay recetas mágicas todo depende del contexto.

Comment: ¿Owner es una clave foránea para libro, verdad? Es una relación que existe en tu base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde mi punto de vista el primer supuesto, tener una consulta específica por id de usuario para la base de datos, es lo correcto.

El segundo supuesto, como comentas, tiene la pega de que te traes todos los datos para ir filtrándolos, haciendo de forma menos eficiente algo que seguramente la base de datos haga mejor.

Y realmente la lógica de negocio, que un usuario sólo pueda consultar sus libros, lo está haciendo la capa de servicio, ya que es la que decide que hay que hacer la consulta por id de usuario. No creo necesario que la capa de servicio se haga cargo del trabajo "duro" (el filtrado) que puede hacer mejor otra herramienta (la base de datos).

Se bueno.

Comment: No lo había visto así, que la capa de servicio decide hacer esa consulta (y supongo que también comprobaría si el usuario es válido y demás si se diera el caso). No había pensado en eso. Gracias!